# How to make a report bug button in add-on?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

When I install a add-on in blender, I want a button to a link for reporting bugs? How can I do it? just like this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Report a Bug* button will be added automatically if you add the `tracker_url` key to the `bl_info` dict of your add-on. See the following example:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "3D Simple X",
    "author": "8N Films",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Toolbar > 3D Simple X",
    "description": "Very Simple and easy! Add everything you want!",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/user/add-on/issues",
    "category": "8N Films",
}
```

More about 'Script Meta Informations' and a complete list of available keys, you can find in the official wiki: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo

Comment: But why the blender link have `"support": "COMMUNITY",` but your script don't have

Comment: `"support": "COMMUNITY",` is the type of your add-on, whether it is OFFICIAL, COMMUNITY or TESTING. Blender's default is COMMUNITY so I don't write the `"support": "COMMUNITY",` code. Please read this link carefully: 
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got it!